Distribute points on top of instances doesn't seem to work
I'm trying to replicate this Houdini tutorial in Blender for practice purposes.
here is the link to the Houdini tutorial
https://youtu.be/zrmFLvwyZwY?feature=shared
Around 50 second mark.
I can't seem to achieve the same result as you see in the picture below. I can’t re-distribute points randomly on to the instances.
I've also shared my node setup.  Hope it helps to explains better. I would be greatly appreciative if anyone could help.



Do you try and change the seeds with some counter incremented every loop ? Because with fixed seeds, Random Number Generators are producing always the same sequence.

Hello Chien,
I didn’t propose you the same result as Houdini but at least your two problems are solved.

First the random problem you just have to install a counter that change the seeds of every random value at every iteration, as said StefLAncien.
The second was to distribute instances at the top : if you input instances then realized them you can sorted them with a Separate Components so the last instances will be the only one to interact because the rest are Meshes.

I hope it help.

EDIT:
I made a new blend witch look far more like the originals Houdini’s system.


First, I had at the end a Mesh Boolean, a  Mesh to Volume and a Volume to Mesh in order to mimic the VDB from Polygons. That mess a bit with the edges (you need to test it, if the resolution is too low you will have a poor the result, if its to hight tour computer may not like it), it’s called ‘Render Definition’ and you setup the Voxel Amount. This setup is switched on and of by the ‘Work Mode’.

In order to have a kind of fractal look, I used a ‘Decrease power’ witch is the Decrease value powered by the Counter. This output value is used by three setups: the Scale of the Instances, The Random Volume and the Depth of the instances on the surface (the setup of the Depth is limited by to values +/- 0.794655, witch is the ratio between the insphere radius and the circumsphere radius of a dodecahedron, so the instances are always touching the emitter surface).

But points are not equally distributed on the instances, at each iteration there is less and less points. So the amount of point have to increase at each iteration. To do so I use a ‘Density Power’ witch increase the amount of points according to the Power of a value you choose (Density Power) by the Counter.

It’s pretty cool too see what Geometry Nodes could achieve…
The update .blend

Edit:
And just for fun:


Thank you so much Fred & StefLAncien, the counter definitely helps. And thanks for giving extra tips too. You guys are awesome! Here is my result: https://i.sstatic.net/F1y0NSVo.png

@Chien I made a better Houdini look alike, I will edit my post soon, with explanations...
